# how to get the manager of mine?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
var users = new[]
{
    new { id = 5, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", }, department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 6, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", }, department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 7, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 8, user_id = 5, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 9, user_id = 6, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 10, user_id = 7, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 11, user_id = 8, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", },  department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 12, user_id = 9, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", },  department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 13, user_id = 10, permissions = new [] { "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 20, user_id = 11, permissions = new [] { "Raspberry", },  department_id = 15, },
};
```

From a list of users and their permissions, I want to find a user's manager.

The manager is a user who has the same department and permissions as the user in question, but they either have more permissions or they work across more departments.

The direct manager is a manager whose departments or permissions are the closest to the user.

for example:

- `user_id=8` => manager = `user_id=5`
- `user_id=5` => manager = `user_id=3`

  - `user_id=3` has 3 department so he is the manager, `user_id=1` has only 1 department.
- `user_id=11` has no manager.

  - `user_id=5` and `user_id=8` has same *department* but not the same permissions
- `user_id=10` => manager = `user_id=3`

  - `user_id=7` is not his manager, they have same department but `user_id=7` is missing a permission.

Comment: This type of data analysis usually indicates that the data is stored incorrectly, its is hard to explain what you want from this because the data looks like it has already been aggregated, so we are forced to "normalise" the information to process it. So whilst we can solve this, there is little value to the community. As a consultant, I would advise altering the structure of the data and/or the data input mechanism to better model the real world process.

Comment: It also helps if you post your attempt and describe the issues that you ran into

Comment: @ChrisSchaller thank you . I also wonder if the structure is not right too. but I am not a good programmer so come here to ask. now I will update the question and hope you to give me a good solution of the structure.

Comment: The other problem is what to do when `user_id=3` is past in, That user has 3 different values of `t_id` => `10,11,12` so id that answer supposed to be `5`, `6` or `7`. You probably need to explain the real world scenario, not just this limited view of the data.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller the real world scenario is I want to find that in the permission structure who should be in from of me. for example in a company I am a role with permission of 'id=11` '` permission then I want to find who is my manager I suppose it to be `id=8` because he has the same "department_id"(t_id) of 10. and who is the manager of `id=8`? I suppose it to be `id=3` because his power is bigger than me.

Comment: I'm sorry, You want to ask a simple question about a recursive permission tree with and example that has _fruits and custard?_ The concept of who is a supervisor of a department and who is a more senior manager is better structured through specific named fields, not an arbitrary collection of permissions, but it's much more relatable like this now.

Comment: because user_id=8 whose department_id=10, so `select user_id from table where department_id=10` => user_id=3,5,8, because `select count(*) from table where user_id in(3,5,8)` => user_id=3 has the most departments && user_id=5 has 1 department && user_id=8 has 1 department, so user_id=3 is the management of user_id=5,8 . Right?

Comment: Because `select count(*) from table where department_id=15` =>1, so the only user whose id is 11 doesn't has manager and he is not an manager as well. Right?

Comment: If so, user_id = 10 's  manager should be user_id=3, because user_id=3 has 3 departments. So `but user_id=3 has permission which user_id=7 not have.` is useless here? which scenario is suitable for the count of permission?

Comment: user_id=3 is the management of user_id = 5 and user_id=5 is the management of user_id=8  

` but user_id=3 has permission which user_id=7 not have ` means user_id =7 and user_id =10 has same department but user_id=7 has no permission which user_id=10 have so user_id=7 is not the management of user_id=10 @TinyWang

Comment: @ChrisSchaller so what do you suggest me to do ?

Comment: The order should like this? Check if the user has other colleagues who are in the same department, then if has other users in the same department, check if there's some one who has more permissions than this user, and check if there's some one has permissions ≥ this user and also belong  to other department.

Comment: @TinyWang seems right.

Comment: okay, hh, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need a single direct linq expression to query all users, but from a first principals I've prepared a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvYRqS

```
    // Get the departments of the passing user
    var userPermissions = permissions.Where(x => x.user_id == userId).ToList();
    var departments = userPermissions.Select(x => x.department_id).ToList();

    // get all the permissions of this user
    var usersPermissionValues = userPermissions.SelectMany(x => x.permissions.Split(';')).Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Distinct().ToArray();
    
    // managers or higher-ups have the same department(s) or more, and the same permissions or more
    var managers = from p in permissions
                   where p.user_id != userId
                   group p by p.user_id into u
                   where departments.All(d => u.Any(x => x.department_id == d))
                   let mgrPermissions = u.SelectMany(x => x.permissions.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))).Distinct().ToList()
                   where !usersPermissionValues.Except(mgrPermissions).Any()
                   select new 
                   {
                       user_id = u.Key, 
                       permissionCount = mgrPermissions.Count(),
                       permissions = String.Join(",", mgrPermissions), 
                       missingPermission = usersPermissionValues.Except(mgrPermissions).Count(),
                       Departments = u.GroupBy(x => x.department_id).Count() 
                   };
    
    // The direct manager is a manager with the lowest count of departments and permissions.
    var directManager = managers.OrderBy(x => x.Departments).ThenBy(x => x.permissionCount).Select(x => x.user_id).FirstOrDefault();
    return directManager == 0 ? null : directManager;
```

Given an array of `permissions` we could query all the users and their direct managers:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/E3iItX

```
IEnumerable<DepartmentUserAccess> permissions = ...
var usersAndDirectManagers = 
           from p in permissions
           group p by p.user_id into user
           let userDepartments = user.Select(x => x.department_id).ToList()
           let userPermissions = user.SelectMany(x => x.permissions.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))).Distinct().ToList()
           select new 
           {
               user_id = user.Key,
               departments = userDepartments,
               permissions = userPermissions,
               manager_id = (from mgr in permissions.Where(x => x.user_id != user.Key).GroupBy(x => x.user_id)
                             where userDepartments.All(d => mgr.Any(x => x.department_id == d))
                             let mgrPermissions = mgr.SelectMany(x => x.permissions.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))).Distinct().ToList()
                             where !userPermissions.Except(mgrPermissions).Any()
                             orderby mgr.Select(x => x.department_id).Count()
                             orderby mgrPermissions.Count()
                             select mgr.Key).Cast<int?>().DefaultIfEmpty((int?)null).First()
            };
```

---

If you had to query this only in a specific report, then I guess it would work. The problem is that the number of permissions or even permissions itself not a very good metric for most software platforms, for this to work you are expecting all possible permissions to be expanded out for each user which is troublesome for role-based security models.

A declarative approach will make the data processing more efficient if you have to do this type of query a lot. If each department has a specific supervisor or manager, then put the supervisor FK on the department table. Otherwise user's supervisor could be defined as an FK on the user table.

Some systems will group the users into teams who have a single supervisor, this model makes it easy to swap out the supervisor whilst still retaining the rest of the team, the team can have a department FK enabling multiple teams per department, or you might even create a M:N relationship between teams and departments if you need to.

A declarative structure would also help to query the reverse, show me the users for each manager, or to build a hierarchical tree showing the CEO at the top, showing for each management level who their direct reports are. You can do it with the current structure, but it's not pretty LINQ or SQL.

Comment: FYI The code in this solution related to the original input data. The original post was updated with a change to express the CSV string of permissions into an array of strings, which relaces the `.Split(';')` in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
var users = new[]
{
    new { id = 5, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", }, department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 6, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", }, department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 7, user_id = 3, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 8, user_id = 5, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 9, user_id = 6, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 10, user_id = 7, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Gooseberry", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 11, user_id = 8, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", },  department_id = 10, },
    new { id = 12, user_id = 9, permissions = new [] { "apple", "Pineapple", },  department_id = 11, },
    new { id = 13, user_id = 10, permissions = new [] { "Gooseberry", "Custard", },  department_id = 12, },
    new { id = 20, user_id = 11, permissions = new [] { "Raspberry", },  department_id = 15, },
};

var userDepartments = users.Select(x => new { x.user_id, x.department_id }).Distinct().ToLookup(x => x.user_id, x => x.department_id);

var query =
    from u in users
    join m in users on u.department_id equals m.department_id
    where u.user_id != m.user_id
    where userDepartments[m.user_id].Count() > 1
        || (m.permissions.Except(u.permissions).Any() && !u.permissions.Except(m.permissions).Any())
    select new { user = u.user_id, manager = m.user_id };
```

That gives me:

[image: managers]